# I am getting an undefined result from my mssql query and i dont understand what this means

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, azure, undefined

Here is the code i am sending through azure database (MS SQL)

```
console.log("About to get your sports");
    var getYourSportsSQL = 'SELECT sport_id FROM [epicatest].[User_Sport] WHERE id = \'' + userId + '\'';
    request.service.mssql.query(getYourSportsSQL,
            {
                success: function(results)
                {
                    console.log("getYourSportsSQL: Success");
                    for(var i = 0; i < getYourSportsSQL.length; i++) 
                    {
                        console.log("YourSports.push[" + results[i] + "]");
                        yourSports.push(results[i]);
                    }
                },
                error : function()
                {
                    console.log("mssql fail getYourSportsSQL");
                    response.send(statusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
                }
            }
        );
```

Normally, the queries are fine in this script and others i have, but this one doesn't seem to like a simple select query. The script is being called from an Android application, but this specific sql query does not use any of the parameters passed in from the application and therefore this eliminates the possibility (i think) that the error comes from there.

I have tested the query on its on in Microsoft Silverlight (via the azure portal's database management interface) and it returns visible results

```
SELECT sport_id FROM [epicatest].[User_Sport] WHERE id = '519894841';
```

[image: Results from the Query]

[image: The actual code inside the azure portal]

Comment: I have deleted my answer cause it was not relevant but my believe is that you are not passing any parameter `userid` to the query. making your query to return empty/null result set and thus getting undefined. check whether you are really passing parameter or not?